# Install Windows Store apps from the command-line

Tags: windows-8, command-line, windows-store, windows-store-app

We can install `AppX packages` (`Metro/Modern/Microsoft-style UI apps`) by using the following PowerShell command:

```
add-appxpackage C:\path-to-app.appx
```

But, I want to install free Windows Store apps from the command line. For example, install the free game `Jetpack Joyride` available on the Windows Store.

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems you need to download it at least once.

Comment: do you want to use system environment only or is it possible for you to install additional software?

Answer (score 5):

For reference: Now it is very much possible with `WinAppDeployCmd install`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894261/can-i-use-winappdeploycmd-install-update-on-pc-itself

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-universal-windows-apps-with-the-winappdeploycmd-tool

Answer (score 5):

First get the `ProductId`. Here is the link for Jetpack Joy:

https://microsoft.com/p/jetpack-joy/9pmw2dsr94ch

so the `ProductId` is `9pmw2dsr94ch`. Then go here:

https://store.rg-adguard.net

change the first option to `ProductId`, then enter the `ProductId`. You can leave
the last option as the default. Then click the checkmark to search. From here you
can download file like this:

```
15609SniperStrikeFPSShoot.JetpackJoy_10.5.0.70_x64__9cjb9ckgksp78.eappx
```

However in this case, since the file type is `eappx`, that is an encrypted file,
so I am not sure what to do with it. Sorry I know that is not too helpful, but I
wanted to post this because in my case, the app I was looking for resulted in an
`appxbundle` file instead, which those can be extracted to give you the `exe`
file. For anyone dealing with `eappx` files, this thread might be helpful:

https://redd.it/56wrda

Answer (score 2):

You could probably achieve this programatically with the follwing three steps :

1. Download the appx file. [Seems to be quite complicated to fully automate](http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/)
2. Enable side loading adding the dword AllowAllTrustedApps=1 to the key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock
3. Use "add-appxpackage C:\path-to-app.appx"

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1> Install Winget

Install Winget by downloading the (.msixbundle) file from the link [Winget Download](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases) OR Install it From Windows Store [App Installer(Winget)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)

### Step 2> Example :

Using WINGET to Install Windows Scan app from microsoft store.
Open the microsoft store in a browser and search the app. If you automatically get redirected to the Store in your pc, use a different browser. This is the link to Windows Scan app.

```
https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFJ3PV?hl=en-us&gl=US
```

Try using NAME or using ID. I prefer ID.
Copy the App ID : 9WZDNCRFJ3PV from the link above.

1. Name : Scan
2. Name : Windows Scan
3. ID : 9WZDNCRFJ3PV

Use the following Command.

```
winget install 9WZDNCRFJ3PV --accept-source-agreements --accept-package-agreements
```

OR

```
winget install scan --accept-source-agreements --accept-package-agreements
```

OR

```
winget install "windows scan" --accept-source-agreements --accept-package-agreements
```

Replace the ID or NAME with whichever app you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Sideloading (the correct name for pre-adding Apps) only works in Enterprise Edition, which is art of a domain and Apps that are signed with your certificate.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305082627/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/scd-odtsp/archive/2012/09/27/windows-8-sideloading-requirements.aspx

Comment: Might have been true in 2012, but nowadays you can sideload with Developer mode enabled, if I'm not mistaken. I don't develop store apps, so I'm not 100% on that. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development "Activate Developer Mode, sideload apps and access other developer features"

Answer (score 0):

As [@nikkdrive18 said in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/1818777/167207):

1. Download **winget**
2. Install using command line (however, just worked for me after adding the `-s msstore`

   ```
   winget install -s msstore "Windows Terminal"
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   winget install -s msstore 9N0DX20HK701
   ```