# Command line interface of Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-store

Is there a command line interface of Microsoft Store that could be used to automate installation of apps from the store?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Windows Store apps from the command-line](https://superuser.com/a/1494050/269373)

Comment: No, not the way you have asked but you can add / remove store apps using powershell.